# Use Nginx to server different pages depending on IP address/subnet

Tags: nginx

For reasons to hideous to go into... I'm using Nginx as a webserver and would like it to serve one page for internal users (say on 10.0.0.0/16) and another page to external users on any other IP address.

For example:

- "Internal" PC with an IP of 10.0.0.34 goes to company.com/page.html gets page internal.html
- "External" PC with an IP of 8.8.8.8 goes to company.com/page.html gets page external.html

Comment: To clarify; Using Nginx isn't hideous, what I need it to do is!  Nginx is great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make use of Nginx [geo module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html). It lets you set variable's value based on a client IP address. `geo` directive must be in `http` section:

```
http {
  geo $client {
    default extra;
    10.0.0.0/8 intra;
  }
```

You can use it later in locations to lookup files

```
location / {
  try_files $uri.$client $uri = 404;
}
```

Which means, Nginx will set `$client` to either `extra` or `intra` based on a client's IP. Let's assume it's a Intranet client. If a client asks for `page.html`, Nginx will search for file `/your/root/page.html.intra`. If there is no such file, it will search for `/your/root/page.html`. If it cannot find neither of these, Nginx returns 404 "Not Found" response. More on "try_files" in the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

By the way, `index` directive supports variables as well. E.g.

```
index index.$client.html index.html;
```

Comment: Worked nicely - I ended up doing location = /filename & rewrite ^ /filename.$client last;