# How to act differently according to the IP address with Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I currently have an application I want accessible for everyone coming from 2 specifics IP address and protecting the same application via the same URL from user coming from another IP.

For example, I allow user having `190.190.190.110` and `190.190.190.112`. And for other people I want Nginx refers to a htpassword file.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Edit: Quick Up

Comment: See this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/267611/use-nginx-to-server-different-pages-depending-on-ip-address-subnet

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   location / {
        satisfy any;

        allow 82.242.75.92;
        allow 82.242.75.98;
        deny all;

        auth_basic            "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /home/password_manager/passwords;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Tested and working.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.. but something like this might work in your server block

```
server  {
  if ($remote_addr !~* "190.190.190.[110|112]") {
     auth_basic            "Restricted";
     auth_basic_user_file  /path/to/htpasswd.file;
  }
}
```

my regular expression might be wrong but that is the jist of how to do it.

Comment: [emerg] "auth_basic" directive is not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I don't think that you can restrict basic-auth based on IP directly, but you can force a redirect to a separate site (i.e. new server-block) that does.</strike>

Check this out:

[Use Nginx to server different pages depending on IP address/subnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/267611/use-nginx-to-server-different-pages-depending-on-ip-address-subnet)

(I need to run and implement this myself...)