# How to set nginx root path based on host

Tags: nginx

How i can set for a visitor host to use a specific root path in nginx?

Visitor with IP 1.1.1.1  will use

```
root /srv/web1
```

all other Visitors will use

```
root /srv/web2
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Drifter104 I have try with if ($remote_addr = 1.1,1,1) { root ... } ... this wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this question is easily answered by simply doing a bit of research and reading the documentation (preferably starting from the [Beginner's Guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) and then [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)), I will answer it anyway.

I assume you have a server with more than one network interface and IP address, where the 1.1.1.1 address is assigned to one interface and other addresses to their respective interfaces.

Nginx is very flexible in this regard, in fact, there always is a `server` block that is used as default when nginx can't match any other server block by `server_name`: that is either the first `server` block of the file or the one which specifies `default_server` in its `listen` directive. And remember that **you can specify an IP in the `listen` directive**.

That means, in your case:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /srv/web2;
    [...]
}
server {
    listen 1.1.1.1:80;
    root /srv/web1;
    [...]
}
```

As you can see in the example above, the first `server` block listens on all interfaces on port 80, while the second block listens only on the 1.1.1.1 interface, on port 80. Therefore, anyone visiting your site through the 1.1.1.1 network interface will receive files from /srv/web1, independently from the Host field in the HTTP request (that is, the domain name written in the URL bar).

Another similar behavior can be obtained by putting the IP address in the `server_name` directive, like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.1.1.1;
    [...]
}
```

* Note that this last `server` block only catches requests to the literal IP address and not to domain names.

I hope this answers your question, but next time please put additional information about your current setup and please do some research.

#### Update

To obtain the described behavior you can use the [*geo* module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html) as explained in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/267611/use-nginx-to-server-different-pages-depending-on-ip-address-subnet):

```
geo $client {
    default web2;
    1.1.1.1 web1;
}
server {
    [...]
    root /srv/$client;
    [...]
}
```

This config uses the *geo* module to set a variable (`$client`) based on the client's IP address. That variable gets set to either the default *web2* or the specific *web1* and then is substituted in the `root` directive.

Note that the `geo` directive must be inside the `http` block and not `server` blocks; the snippet above should work as-is, but I don't guarantee anything since I did not test it.

Comment: sorry my questions was not well written, I need a solution that specific visitors are server by a different root path, means visitor with IP 1.1.1.1 will be server by /srv/web1 and all other by /srv/web2

Comment: @nenad007 I updated my answer (down below, 'Update' section). If it works for you, feel free to accept the answer.

And regarding your other comment about `if($remote_addr...)`, it doesn't work because you cannot put a `root` directive inside an `if` block. Read [If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).